# メソッドの呼び出し先でcontinue文が使えない。

Tags: java

繰り返し処理で配列の要素が3の場合はcontinue文を使って処理を飛ばしたいのですがコンパイルエラーが出て「continueはループの外側では使用できない」と表示されます。for文を使うクラスとは別のクラスにはcontinue文は使用できないのでしょうか。

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        checkService aaa = new checkService();

        int hairetu[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        for (int i = 0; i < hairetu.length; i++) {
            aaa.checkContuine(i);
        }
    }
}

public class checkService {

    public void checkContuine(int i){

        if(i == 3){
            continue;
        }

        if(i == 4){
            System.out.println("4です");
        }else{
            System.out.println("3と4以外の数値です");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

使用できません。何故かといえば、`checkService.checkContuine`が本当にループの中で呼ばれるかがコンパイラには分からないからでしょう。

`i`が3の時に出力を抑制したいという事なら、単に`return`すれば事足ります。

例：

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkService aaa = new checkService();
        int hairetu[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        for (int i = 0; i < hairetu.length; i++) {
            aaa.checkContuine(i);
        }
    }
}

class checkService {
    public void checkContuine(int i){
        if(i == 3) return;

        if(i == 4){
            System.out.println("4です");
        }else{
            System.out.println("3と4以外の数値です");
        }
    }
}
```